# Display post category in foreach loop

Tags: posts, php, categories

I am trying to display post category in a foreach loop.  I have all the elements displaying properly except for the category. Here is my function:

```
function my_get_display_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

$output = '<ul>';
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $authors_post->ID ), 'related-author' );
    $output .= '<li>
    <a class="title" href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">
    <strong>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</strong>
    <img src="'.$image[0].'"> 
    </a>
    <span>'.get_the_time('m.d.y').'</span>'.the_category('', '', $authors_post->ID).'
    </li>';
}
$output .= '</ul>';

return $output;}
```

Follow the following link to see the current output.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s250/sh/0e3c6bf9-5676-4d56-acdf-ee6f53285acf/fa43094ca54f018c0e517b4e678d4231

How can I wrap the_category function under html output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `foreach` loop is from `get_posts()`, you need to run `setup_postdata()` for each post if you want to use themplate tags inside the loop like `the_category()`, if not you can get unexpected behaviour. Also, you will need to run `wp_reset_postdata()` after the `foreach` loop. Note that `the_category` and similar template tags actually displays/echoes the output, so, if you want to concatenate the output in a string you should use `get_the_category()` instead.

```
function my_get_display_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

    $output = '<ul>';

    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {

        // Build a comma separated categories list
        // You can customize as needed
        // or use get_the_category_list() for quick and delimited list of categories
        // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list
        $categories = get_the_category($authors_post->ID);
        $categories_string = '';
        $separator = ', ';
        if($categories) {
            foreach($categories as $category){
                $categories_string .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
            }
            $categories_string = trim($categories_string, $separator);
        }

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($authors_post->ID), 'related-author' );
        $output .= '<li>
        <a class="title" href="' . get_permalink($authors_post->ID) . '">
        <strong>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</strong>
        <img src="'.$image[0].'"> 
        </a>
        <span>'.get_the_time('m.d.y', $authors_post->ID ).'</span>'.$categories_string.'
        </li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I got the following outpout 
`World’s Largest Economies`
`2014 04.30.14 Array`

Comment: `get_the_category()` turned into Array

Comment: I forget `get_the_category()` returns an array. See edtired answer.

Comment: Works but without link.

Comment: As the comment inside the loop says, you can customize the `$categories_string` as you want or need. I've added each category as link to the category's archive page. Please, note that your question is already answered and working; I can not provide the exact output you want because you have not ask about it, your question was about "Display post category inside a foreach loop" in general. If you need a specific output, please, say to us.

Comment: Sorry my mistake actually it doesn't work as I wanted. It repeat same category without link. I got the following result

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s250/sh/ba2c1f8f-c06e-44ef-b004-c0432b7d3a5f/12febb0db08fd9a749eee779051cb007/deep/0/Fullscreen-02-05-14-3-35-pm.png

Comment: I've tested the code as it is and it works as expected. I've edited the code again and remove `setup_postdata()` function because finally template tags are not used. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

`the_category()` function must be used inside the loop. You can use [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function instate.

So the new code is

```
      function my_get_display_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $authors_post->ID ), 'related-author' );
    }       
        $output .= '<li>
        <a class="title" href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">
        <strong>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</strong>
        <img src="'.$image[0].'"> 
        </a>
        <span>'.get_the_time('m.d.y').'</span>'.get_the_category_list(', ', '', $authors_post->ID).'
        </li>';
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a proper structured answer. This not an answer but a comment. Please see the structure of @cybnet answer

Comment: The proposed code won't work if the post is attached to multiple categories beacuse it outputs only the name of the first category object returned by `get_the_category()`

Comment: Sorry, works but without link.

Comment: @Hussain Ansari I added the category link also

Comment: @cybnet I used the get_the_category_list() function now to get all the category name with link